# Where should I ask a question about precision of weight scales?

Tags: discussion, questions, site-recommendation

I have asked a question "[How precise are ordinary inexpensive kitchen scales?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/352027/)" on the Physics Stack Exchange. There is no proper answer, besides mine, and now it is marked as "off-topic". (It also went off-topic due to terminology problem: weight/scale, accuracy/precision)

After posing the question I found a quite related question at (surprisingly) Cooking Stack Exchange [How accurate are kitchen scales?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/35579/)

It seems to be fairly difficult to find where similar questions have been posed, - before you post the question. I see now that the perhaps best way is to use an internet search engine with the word "stackexchange" in the query. This identifies a range of related questions, for instance: [How can I measure / weigh really small quantities?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/83214/how-can-i-measure-weigh-really-small-quantities/83234),
[How to deal with inaccurate luggage weighing scales at an airport](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/24535/how-to-deal-with-inaccurate-luggage-weighing-scales-at-an-airport) and [How can you accurately determine your own mass?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/136736/). So the question is halfway answered on some Stack Exchanges, but I am wondering whether there is any better Stack Exchange beyond Physics to answer such questions?

Comment: Re a Google search, you can use `site:stackexchange.com`

Comment: Or the 'search all sites' option in the topbar of https://stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depends on what you're doing with those scales.

- If you're preparing food, [Seasoned Advice](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/measuring-scales) is a great place to ask.
- If you're preparing cats, [Pets](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/15038/best-brand-of-scale-for-kittens)
- If you're preparing babies, [Parenting](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/30937/how-to-weigh-a-newborn-at-home)
- If you're preparing entire worlds, [Worldbuilding](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/63832/standardized-measurement-for-trade-between-world-with-different-gravity)
- If you're comparing Apples to Apples, [Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/208761/magsafe-85w-weight)
- If you're connecting your scale to an Arduino, ask on [Arduino](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/11946/how-to-get-weight-data-from-glass-electronic-bathroom-scale-sensors)
- If you're connecting your scale to a Raspberry Pi, well... [You get the idea.](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/47266/reading-data-from-accupost-usb-scale)
- Note that there's also an [Electrical Engineering site](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/211023/convert-usb-scale-output-to-serial) if your project doesn't involve some trendy board.
- And of course, we have an English site for [questions about the difference between precision and accuracy](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/30498/are-accuracy-and-precision-interchangeable-nouns).

In short, we tend to create sites for specific occupations / activities / interests - whatever specific activity matches yours, that's probably the site for your question.

Comment: My initial interest was for a inexpensive and portable scale for scientific experiments for "reasonable" approximate measurements. So it seems that Physics SE (where I asked) could be relevant. I do not see a SE more experimentally oriented site.